# IE mode is opening file://server/xyz/abc.zip in network drive instead of downloading

Tags: internet-explorer

So we have a server in which there is a folder. Inside the folder there are files with different extensions including zip file.

When I click on the hyperlinks pointing to the files in folder interesting things happen

When the hyperlink is

1. File://servername/xyz/abc.xlsx --- it asks for open/save/cancel which is expected case
2. File://servername/xyz/def.zip ---- it opens the file explorer and located the file under network drive \servername\xyz\def.zip ---- this I don't want. I want to have the dialog box for download pop up.

I have tried looking into mime type
.zip is already added there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Browser behaviors usually have nothing to do with the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test the issue on my side and got similar results as yours.

I noticed that the Excel file got downloaded but the Zip file opens File explorer.

The reason is you have set File explorer as a Default app to open the Zip files and File explorer has the ability to extract the Zip files in the latest Windows OS.

1. If you want to download the Zip file from the IE mode then you could try to set the Microsoft Edge browser as the Default app to open the Zip files on your Windows OS.

[image]

2. Go to `edge://settings/downloads` in the Edge browser and enable the option **Ask me what to do with each download**.

[image]

Output:

[image]